# Nullspace containing whole space

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem: find a $1\times3$ matrix whose nullspace consists of all vectors in $\mathbf{R}^3$ such that $x_1 + 2\times x_2+4\times x_3 = 0$.
Answer from book (Linear Algebra and Applications): $(1,2,4)$

How can nullspace contain all vectors in $\mathbf{R}^3$ if it should contain only 2 special solution at most(number of columns - rank)?

Answer (score 1):

It says all vectors *such that* $x_1 + 2x_2+4x_3 = 0$, which is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbf{R}^3$.

For example you can pick the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Hello! Let's have an example of vector in R3 - (1,1,1) - which is not in the nullspace of the matrix; thus, its nullspace does not consist of all vectors in R3.

Comment: @S.Drumble1 exactly